# MySQL-based search not bringing up full results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

So I have a MySQL table, people, with the fields _Name, _Criminal, _Loyalist, _PrevJailed and three people in the database.

```
_Name           |   _Criminal   |   _Loyalist   |   _PrevJailed   
-----------------------------------------------------------
John Mitt       |   1           |   0           |   1
John Sample     |   0           |   1           |   1
Jane Lastname   |   0           |   0           |   1
```

When searching for people with the query

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE `_Name` LIKE '%'
    AND _Criminal = 1
    AND `_Loyalist` = 0
    AND `_PrevJailed` = 1
```

It brings up John Mitt, as I predicted. But when searching with a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE `_Name` LIKE '%'
    AND _Criminal = 0
    AND `_Loyalist` = 0
    AND `_PrevJailed` = 1
```

It only brings up Jane Lastname. It should be bringing up John Sample *and* John Mitt, because they've all been previously jailed. I've been stumped for three days on this issue. My current system works, you just need to be *very* specific when searching (ie state their exact 'record' (0,0,1 etc).

Comment: Huh?AND requires all conditions to be true,maybe you need OR.

Comment: Using OR brings up the entire table (around 60 records), even when _Criminal, _Loyalist, and _PrevJailed are all zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM people
WHERE `_PrevJailed` = 1 
AND (_Criminal = 0 OR `_Loyalist` = 0)
```